# How to use a photos location data

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, geolocation

WHen I take a photo I want to save the location (Latitude, Longitude). Should I Use the `locationManager startUpdatingLocation` when `UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` is called or is there some other way to get the location data itself from the photo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest way will be to use

```
 func getLocation() {
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}
```

And get the lat and long from there

Comment: just remember to add `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` `Privacy - Location Usage Description`  in your info.plist

Comment: `locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` Only one of these is required not both.

Comment: Just added both to give both options, but adding both will let the `locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()` override the  `locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` soo its fine to add both

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
import CoreLocation
```

after it add CLLocationManagerDelegate To your View controller class declaration header

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .NotDetermined
    {


        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    }


        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

This delegate will called for location change

```
 func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!,
            didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!)
        {
      let location = locations.last as CLLocation
      self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
```

This delegate will called there is problem in location Manager

```
 func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!,
            didFailWithError error: NSError!)
        {

    }
```

Hope it helps.